# Python Can't compare a file's contents with if statement

Tags: python, file, colors

Ok, so I have a file called cl.DAT that contains a color. The file is read and I then I match it's contents with a system function that changes the text color. The file is opened fine, but even when the file matches with a color (I've checked for whitespace) nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
import os
import time
color_setting_file = file("cl.dat")
print "The file says the color is " + color_setting_file.read()

if str(color_setting_file.read()) == "blue":
        os.system('color 9')
        print "set blue"
if str(color_setting_file.read()) == "green":
        os.system('color a')
        print "set green"
if str(color_setting_file.read()) == "white":
        os.system('color 7')
        print "set white"
if str(color_setting_file.read()) == "red":
        os.system('color 4')
        print "set red"
if str(color_setting_file.read()) == "yellow":
        os.system('color 6')
        print "set yellow"
if color_setting_file.read() == "pink":
        os.system('color 47')
        print "set pink"
else:
        print("None of the above.")
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the results of `color_setting_file.read()` in a variable and check that, rather than calling it multiple times.

As is, you're getting an empty string back from `color_setting_file.read()`, since the end of the file has been reached. [See the python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

eg:

```
import os
import time
color_setting_file = file("cl.dat")
color = color_setting_file.read()
print "The file says the color is " + color

if str(color) == "blue":
        os.system('color 9')
        print "set blue"
if str(color) == "green":
        os.system('color a')
        print "set green"
if str(color) == "white":
        os.system('color 7')
        print "set white"
if str(color) == "red":
        os.system('color 4')
        print "set red"
if str(color) == "yellow":
        os.system('color 6')
        print "set yellow"
if str(color) == "pink":
        os.system('color 47')
        print "set pink"
else:
        print("None of the above.")
time.sleep(10)
```